# How can I control the frequency about how snakemake submitting the job?

Tags: python, snakemake

Now, I'm using snakemake cluster to execute with my own k8s.

When submitting the task, the command looks like:

export TMP=/k8s &&  snakemake --cluster "lsub" --cluster-config cluster-config.yaml -j 2

The brief lsub script logic:

1. read the parameters from snakemake
2. submit a k8s job via:
   cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
   xxxxxxxx
   EOF
   (the origin sub-step shell from snakemake is included in command section in xxxxxxxxx)

Due to the k8s environment's throttling policy, I cannot submit too many jobs concurrently. However, it seems that snakemake cannot control it's submitting behavior.(I can control the first step. However, I cannot control the follow-up step)

My idea is changing the lsub script to control the frequency. However, I have no idea about it since I don't know how snakemake read the job status.

So, any suggestion about this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [`--max-jobs-per-second`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#BEHAVIOR) option.  If you set that to 0.1 snakemake will submit a job every 10 seconds.

If instead you mean the number of jobs snakemake will actively submit, you want to modify the `--jobs` option.  `--jobs 100` will make sure only 100 jobs are running (submitted) at once.